# NSNotificationCenter not working with Custom Keyboard

Tags: ios, keyboard, swift

I am developing a custom keyboard using Swift. I want to get UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification when Orientation changes; for that purpose, I am using:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "changeOrientation:", name: UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification, object: nil)

func changeOrientation(notification: NSNotification) {  }
```

It works with a simple app, but doesn't work with custom keyboard extension.

Comment: Same here. I am trying to find a way to get notified when device orientation changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To anyone new to Extensions

Select your extension target, Select 'play' it will ask you to chose an app to run. Select an appropriate app.

Then you are running with the debugger attached to your extension and can use breakpoints.

-Dan

Answer (score 0):

What did you put in your changeOrientation function ?
Breakpoints aren't working for me in the keyboard swift file.